# How can I make a tkinter button pass an id of itself when executing it's command

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to generate some buttons dynamically in tkinter, and that each button when it's pushed executes a command which passes and identifier to the function of which button was pushed, for example:

`command = function(ButtonId)`

and I am generating the buttons like this

```
for button in range(nbuttons):

        buttons.append(tk.Button(master = ButtomFrame, text = 'text', command = lambda : function(button)))
```

The problem is that as I am defining a lambda when the value of button is updated the value passed to the function is too. I've been trying to find a way to make this work where I can program them in bulk and pass an independent number as their id, but up to now I just have been able to do so if I program each button one by one manually.

Comment: Try `command=lambda n=len(buttons): function(buttons[n])`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks! It worked, mind if you explain why it works? I have an idea but I don't get it completely. Thanks!